# BIRT Dynamic Text in CSV Output

Tags: birt

I've just starting trying out eclipse BIRT to generate reports, but am unable to get the "Dynamic Text" option working when I output to a CSV file, it works fine on other output types.

Is there a way round this? Really would like to be able to output report parameters within the output file using this step.

Thanks in advance.

Tom

Comment: Found the cause, by changing the content type within the Property Editor for each of the "dynamic text" objects to "auto" (was HTML) they are now outputted correctly for both HTML and CSV output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the cause, by changing the content type within the Property Editor for each of the "dynamic text" objects to "auto" (was HTML) they are now outputted correctly for both HTML and CSV output.

Answer (score 0):

Not able to Export report to CSV....

Export report->Select csv.. Reprot is getting downlaoded as .csvfile. Open that .csvfile in browser firefox there is a error as follows

org.eclipse.birt.report.service.api.ReportServiceException: Error happened while running the report.
AxisFault

faultCode: {

faultSubcode:

faultString: org.eclipse.birt.report.service.api.ReportServiceException: Error happened while running the report.

faultActor:

faultNode:

faultDetail:

```
{http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:org.eclipse.birt.report.service.api.ReportServiceException: Error happened while running the report.

at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.ReportEngineService.throwDummyException(ReportEngineService.java:1106)

at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.ReportEngineService.renderReport(ReportEngineService.java:1553)

at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.BirtViewerReportService.renderReport(BirtViewerReportService.java:369)
```